# How to save enumerate output to a.txt?

Tags: python-2.7, output, enumerate

I have some question about enumerate, I can't save output to txt

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import codecs
f = codecs.open('abc.txt', 'w', 'utf-8')

data = ['a','a','b','c']
search_table = {}

for i, tag_list_2 in enumerate(data): 
    for tag in tag_list_2: 
        if tag not in search_table:
            search_table[tag] = set()
            print tag 
            f.write(tag + "\n")
f.close()
```

I really don't know why print tag can't write in `f.write(tag + "\n")`

Comment: This will definitely work. Did you receive any error?

Comment: mm i check ,thank you

Comment: Whether you got any output in txt file?

Comment: @Prabhakar thank ,i forget f.write(tag + "\n") in my runing code